# How to prevent numeric arrays in a data.frame from becoming character when returned from function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, return-value

I am having an issue that my function that processes an array of numeric values and returns a data.frame object, the processed values become characters when I want the numeric values to stay numeric

```
myfun=function(x,name){
 m=mean(x)
 s=sd(x)
 df=data.frame(type=name, mu=m, sig=s)
 return(df)
}

> out=myfun(rnorm(10),'read1')
> out
    type        mu       sig
    1 read1 0.2992288 0.6134481
 > apply(out,2,class)
       type          mu         sig 
  "character" "character" "character"
```

How can I return the output of this function so that the 
mu and sig values stay as.numeric without me explicitly having to do

```
 as.numeric(as.character(out$mean))
```

Thanks

Comment: You are using the wrong way to find the class.  Use `lapply(out, class)` or `sapply(out, class)`.  The reason is that `apply` converts to `matrix` and matrix can hold only a single class.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize this (I am new to r)